# Proof: $CA = I_n$ and $AD = I_m \Rightarrow C = D$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my school book there's an exercise:

We have three matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $C, D \in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.
If $CA = I$ and $AD = I$ than we can say that $C = D$.
Proof this.

*Hint*: work with the product $C\cdot A\cdot D$.

I ignored the hint and I tried to prove it. This is what I got:

\begin{align*}
CA = I &\wedge AD = I\\
&\Updownarrow\\
C = A^{-1} &\wedge D = A^{-1}\\
&\Updownarrow \text{ The inverse of a regular matrix is unique}\\
C &= A
\end{align*}
**EDIT: I just saw this proof is wrong, because were not working with square matrices.**
Now I've got two questions.

- Is my own proof correct? **I guess not**
- How would you prove it by working with the product $C\cdot A\cdot D$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see how the hint applies, try this:

$C=CI_m=CAD=I_nD=D$

Comment: QED. There's nothing left to try!

Comment: @MarkSchwarzmann truth.

Comment: @AMPerrine thank you anyway. If I see it, it looks easy.

Comment: Sorry if I showed too much.  I tried only giving away a part, but since the symmetry of the equations made the other steps very obvious it felt more incomplete than a useful hint.

Comment: A hint could have been $C(AD)=(CA)D$.